# How can I solve the throwing two dices question in Python 3.10

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code about a problem that I should solve it with function wrote a code but it did not work with a true way.

Here is the code:

```
def dice(dice1,dice2):
    dice1=random.randint(1,7)
    dice2=random.randint(1,7)
    return(dice1,dice2)

dicee=0
dicee2=0

count=1
while count!=-1:
    toplam=0
    print(dice(dicee, dicee2))
    if dice == dicee2:
        sum=sum+dicee+dicee2
        print(sum)
        count += 1
    elif dice != dice:
        sum=sum+dicee+dicee2
        print("Conclusion:{}".format(sum))
        break
```

Comment: When you assign value to `dice1` in a function, the value of `dicee` doesn't change

Comment: You can change the names while using function.That part is working actually.

Comment: Calling the function does not change the values of `dicee` and `dicee2`. You need to assign the returned values to `dicee` and `dicee2`, i.e. `dicee, dicee2 = dice()` (also passing arguments to `dice` doesn't make any sense as they are't used - resigned in the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing parameters *to* the function, you need to assign the output *from* the function to your local variables:

```
import random

def dice():
    return (random.randint(1,7), random.randint(1,7))

sum_of_dice = 0

while True:
    # roll dice
    dice1, dice2 = dice()
    
    # print roll result
    print(f"Rolled: {(dice1, dice2)}")
    
    # update rolling sum
    sum_of_dice += dice1 + dice2
    
    # stop rolling if the die faces are different
    if dice1 != dice2:
        break

# print final sum
print(f"Sum: {sum_of_dice}")
```

Sample output:

```
Rolled: (1, 1)
Rolled: (4, 1)
Sum: 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It is compiling but I am still confused about the question.Did I understand correctly?When the numbers are same should program be finished?My english level is not good enough so I could not understand.

Comment: @stck_n I can't answer that, you'll have to ask whoever posed the problem in the first place :)